# Convergence of a sequence in a norm space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a normed space $C([0,1])$ i.e. space of continuous function on [0,1] with norm
$$\lVert f \rVert _\infty = \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \mid f(x) \, \mid $$
My sequence is
$$\sum _{n\ge1} {(-t)^n \over n}$$
I know that sequence is convergent in a normed space if there exists an element in space whose difference with sequence has norm  equal to zero
Mathematically
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \lVert \sum _{n\ge1} {(-t)^n \over n} - f\rVert _\infty =0  \,f \in C([0,1]) $$
$$ \lVert -\ln (1+t) - f\rVert _\infty  = 0 \, f \in C([0,1]) 
$$
$$ -\ln (1+t) - f = 0$$
$$f = - \ln(1+t) \, t \in [0, 1]$$
which shows that the sequence is convergent. Have I done step and procedure correctly or there are flaws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the assertion “sequence is convergent in a normed space if there exists an element in space whose difference with sequence has norm equal to zero” makes no sense. What is the difference between an element of a normed space and a sequence of elements of that space?

But I agree that, if you want to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-t)^n}n=-\log(1+t)$ in $\bigl(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty\bigr)$, then what you have to prove is that$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\left\|-\log(1+t)-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-t)^n}n\right\|_\infty=0.\tag1$$But you did not prove it. This follows from [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem): since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n$ converges, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}nt^n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$. Now, use the fact that$$(\forall t\in[0,1)):\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}nt^n=-\log(1+t).$$Since the convergence is uniform, we have that the equality $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}nt^n=-\log(1+t)$ also holds when $t=1$, and so $(1)$ is indeed true.